# Sort lines while grouping indented lines with their parent

Tags: sort

I have an index-of-a-book-like list of lines, say

```
day
    satur-
    sun-
    holy-
night
    ball
    to-
eve
    election
    christmas
```

Now I want to sort these lines in the obvious fashion: I want to group every “parent”-entry (`day`, `night`, `eve`) with their respective indented “child”-entries (`satur-`, `sun-`, …) and sort these groups by their parent-entry.  I also want to sort the child-entries within any given group.

Thus, the desired output is:

```
day
    holy-
    satur-
    sun-
eve
    christmas
    election
night
    ball
    to-
```

How would I best achieve this by using unix core tools like `sort`?

Comment: `vim` can solve the second half of your question with the this: `GqqV?^\w<CR>j:sor<CR>kkq`.  It defines a macro, `q`, which you can execute with `@q` to sort each subsection and move up to the previous.  Sorting the actual sections I'm still looking into.  Does `vim` count as a core tool?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could pick a character that's unlikely to occur in your text file, prepend the parent name + that character to each child line, sort then remove the parent name and the separator from each child line e.g. with `gnu` sed and a low ascii char like `\x02`

```
sed '/^[^[:blank:]]/h;//!G;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\x02\1/' infile | sort | sed 's/.*\x02//'
```

How it works:
the 1st `sed` does the following:
`/^[^[:blank:]]/h` - copy non indented lines (parents) over hold space
`//!G` - on indented lines (children) append hold space content to pattern space
`s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\x02\1/` - swap lines in pattern space replacing the `\n`ewline with `\x02`
after that, `sort` and remove everything up to and including `\x02` with a 2nd `sed 's/.*\x02//'`

Comment: That’s a good idea, thanks. Can you explain a bit how this first sed line works?

Comment: Yeah, it is! I get it know. It’s a great solution, thank you!

Comment: Worth noting that this isn't recusive - the OP asked for only two levels of sorting so this doesn't help those of us looking for a more general solution. :/